# Extract Sentence from Text Using Match Againt MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, substring, match

I am currently working on a **Arabic** book website based on PHP and MySQL
I have the following Query

```
SELECT page_content FROM `book` WHERE MATCH(page_content) Against('رائد' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

when users search for specific text we run this query and it gets matching words from all available books successfully but,
we have each page of the book in a row, the issue is that the query gets **the whole page content text** and now we want to get the exact search word ( first occurrence ) + 5 words after and 5 words before

for example

> المقالة نوع من الأدب، هي قطعة إنشائية، ذات طول معتدل تُكتب نثراً،
> وتُهتمُّ بالمظاهر الخارجية للموضوع بطريقة سهلةٍ سريعة، ولا تعنى إلا
> بالناحية التي تمسُّ الكاتب عن قرب. رأى النور في عصر النهضة الأوروبية،
> واتخذ مفهومه من محاولات التي أطلق عليها اسم Essais، و"الفصل" (صيد
> الخاطر) كما عرفه العرب أقدم رائد للمقالة في الآداب العالمية، ذلك أن
> الفصل في الأدب العربي قد ظهر قبل ظهور مقالات مونتاني إمام هذا الفن غير
> مدافع بين الأوروبيين، فقد ظهر فن المقالة لأول مرة في فرنسا سنة 1571م،
> ثم ظهر بعد ذلك ببضع عشرة سنة في كتابات فرانسيس بيكون، ثم أصبحت المقالة
> منذ ذلك الحين فناً إنكليزياً شائعاً بين قراء الإنكليزية مع سبق
> الفرنسيين إليه.

so when the user search for رائد they will only get
(صيد الخاطر) كما عرفه العرب أقدم رائد للمقالة في الآداب العالمية
Instead of the whole page text, I tried to use

1. SUBSTRING_INDEX
2. SUBSTRING
3. POSITION

but sometimes the user may write رأئد instead of رائد the MySQL match query will get the result correctly but position and substring don't get the same results.

The question is how to use position and substring with match query to get the position of the first occurrence and to get the 5 words after and 5 words before

Comment: I tried to use LOCATE but It require full match not partial match too

Comment: I was thinking about something like explode the array to one word each and make foreach and get the index of word by checking the match word 
SELECT MATCH ('رأئد ') AGAINST ('رائد' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
like the STRCMP Query
Select STRCMP('رأئد ', 'رائد') As 'Cmp_Value'
but it's not to possible to run that query It needs fulltext index column

Answer (score 0):

I've used levenshtein function on php after exploding the text into array
and got the closest match index using foreach loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).